# NullPointerException on EJB class while sending email with JavaMail

Tags: jsp, servlets, ejb, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send an email with JavaMail. I used an EJB @Stateless and @LocalBean, but it gave me NullPointerException when I try to send mail.

My servlet looks like this:

```
package com.lsp.web;

import com.lsp.service.Mailer;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@WebServlet(name = "contact", urlPatterns = {"/contact"})
public class ContactServlet extends SpringInjectedServlet {
@EJB
private Mailer emailBean;

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    req.getRequestDispatcher("contact.jsp").forward(req, resp);
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String customerEmail = req.getParameter("email");
    String subject = req.getParameter("subject");
    String body = req.getParameter("message");

    String error = null;
    String succMess = null;

    try {
        javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress ia = new javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress(customerEmail);
        ia.validate();
        //LINE 34 emailBean.send(customerEmail, subject, body); ------>NullPointerException
        req.setAttribute("succMessage", succMess);
        req.getRequestDispatcher("sent.jsp").forward(req, resp);

    } catch (javax.mail.internet.AddressException ae) {
        error = "您指出的邮箱地址不存在";
        req.setAttribute("errorMessage", error);
        req.getRequestDispatcher("contact.jsp").forward(req, resp);
    }
    catch (MessagingException mex) {
        error = "发送失败";
        req.setAttribute("errorMessage", error);
        req.getRequestDispatcher("contact.jsp").forward(req, resp);
    }
}
}
```

Then my EJB class Mailer is:

```
package com.lsp.service;

import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import java.util.Properties;

@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class Mailer {
public void send(String from, String subject, String body) {
    String to = "jshao745@gmail.com";
    String host = "localhost";

    Properties properties = System.getProperties();
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

    try{
        // Create a default MimeMessage object.
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

        // Set From: header field of the header.
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

        // Set To: header field of the header.
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));

        // Set Subject: header field
        message.setSubject(subject);

        // Send the actual HTML message, as big as you like
        message.setText(body);

        // Send message
        Transport.send(message);
        System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
    }catch (MessagingException mex) {
        mex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Then after insert message on my submit form on JSP and hit submit, I got this exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
com.lsp.web.ContactServlet.doPost(ContactServlet.java:34)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
com.lsp.web.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:39)
```

Inside pom.xml, I added these dependencies:

```
<!--JavaMail API-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--EJB-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>ejb-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Java activation-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--EJB LocalBean-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>ejb31-api-experimental</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

I guess it has to do with EJB, but I am not sure where I did wrong.

Also, I currently don't have anything on ejb-jar.xml. Do I need to edit it?

I appreciate if someone could help me.

Comment: please give more information about your environment; what App server are you using? how did you packaged the app? are the servlet and ejb container running in different JVM?

Comment: I am using IntelliJ and I added all jar files in Project Modules. Since I am also using maven, I added all required dependencies in pom.xml.

Comment: IntelliJ is an IDE, not a server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat is not an EJB Container, thus it doesn't know what an EJB is.
The annotation `@Stateless`, `@LocalBean` and `@EJB` are just ignored in a web container.

Your `Mailer` class deployed in Tomcat is just a POJO, the fact that it is annotated with `@Stateless` and `@LocalBean` 
doesn't makes the class an EJB.

In the same way, the `@EJB` annotation used in `ContactServlet` class to inject a `Mailer` instance is also ignored, 
Tomcat doesn't provide this kind of service. Due to no one has initialized the `emailBean` instance member, 
a NullPointer exception is thrown when you try to use it (like any other object).

The JavaEE specification defines several kinds of components, 
some of them run within a web container (servlets, jsp) and others like ejb need a EJB container. 
 I suggest that you read some [articles](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/tutorial/doc/Overview4.html) about JEE basic architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Please go ahead and check the instance of the `emailBean`. It is not getting injected correctly and is most likely `null`.

Put a debug point and you should be able to validate if that is the reason for the `NullPointerException`.

The fix is dependent on the environment and settings, which will enable a proper instance to be available.